# Preventing jumping text when an image is inserted

Tags: jquery, html, css

In a voting system I have a line that gives a score as follows:

```
<span>Score: <span id="numberOfVotes">{$numberOfVotes}</span></span>
```

Every time a user votes, clicks Next or chooses another item the score is updated. During this update, the "0" is replaced with a loading animation that is 16x16 pixels.

How can I avoid text shifting when the innerHtml of #numberOfVotes is temporarily swapped around with the loading animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `span` to `display:inline-block;` and giving it `height` and `width` to contain that image... maybe 16px each or greater.  *Untested!*

Comment: That's an idea. I changed the enclosing span to a div (content is being placed vertically in the page) and set the CSS of #numberOfVotes to `display:inline-block;display:inline-block;height:30px;min-width:25px;`. There's no more shift to the left.

Now, the text in both the div and the span are positionned at the top of containers and `border:solid 1px;` shows that the box of #numberOfVotes is pushing down. Ideally, the contents of #numberOfVotes should be positionned at the bottom as the animation appears to be higher than the character it's being swapped around with.

Comment: Sure. Will post a link just below. The shift happens when you click the "Next" button up top or click one of the thumbnails positioned around the center. P.S: The site's style guide was done by a predecessor.

Comment: I see the issue.  Try setting `vertical-align:top;` on the `div`

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you very much :) . Adding `text-align: left;` to the span should take care of multiple digits.